# Clickable links in android using eclipse

Tags: android, json, eclipse, textview, onclicklistener

I am trying to make strings in the text view clickable.My `textview` consists of name of various online questions and i want them to redirect the user to the url of the question when clicked.Can anyone recommend changes to my code.

In the following code "result" is the final textview consisting of name of questions .

```
public class Http extends Activity {

TextView httpStuff;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;
final static String URL = "http://codeforces.com/api/user.status?handle=";
String m = "";
public static  String[] sarr = new String[200];
public static String[] name = new String[200];
public static int cnt = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpex);

    httpStuff = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Read().execute("result");
}

public JSONObject lastSub(String username) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(username);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    int status = 0;
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONObject last = new JSONObject(data);
        //JSONObject last = new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("problem");

        return last;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(Http.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;

    }
}

public class Read extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String add = "&from=1&count=100";
            String input = (Mainapp.p);
            input = input.concat(add);
            json = lastSub(input);
            JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("result");
            String m1=null, m2=null, m3=null;
            String n1 = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            int flag=0;
            for(int k=0; k<array.length() && cnt<15; k++)
            {
                JSONObject json1 = array.getJSONObject(k).getJSONObject("problem");
                JSONObject v = array.getJSONObject(k);
                if(v.getString("verdict").contentEquals("OK")) {
                    m1 = json1.getString("name");
                    m2= json1.getString("contestId");
                    m2= m2.concat("/");
                    m3= json1.getString("index");
                    m2 = m2.concat(m3);
                    flag = 0;
                    for(int i=0; i<cnt ; i++) {
                        if (sarr[i].equals(m1)) {
                            flag = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag == 0) {
                        m = m.concat(m1);
                        m= m.concat(n1);
                        sarr[cnt] = m1;
                        name[cnt] = m2;
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return m;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "INVALID USER NAME";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
            httpStuff.setText(result);
        }
    }



  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use question name as hyperlink

```
String html = "<html> Visit <a href=\"http://codeforces.com/api/question1\">Question1</a> </html>";
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to not only make links clickable but also # and @ are clickable

Create a new file called InternalURLSpan.java and paste this code into it:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;


public class InternalURLSpan extends android.text.style.ClickableSpan {
    public String text;

    public static Context context;

    public InternalURLSpan(Context contex){
        this.context = context;     
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        handleLinkClicked(text, widget.getContext());
    }

    public void handleLinkClicked(String value, Context context) {
        if (value.startsWith("http")) {     
            // Open the url with the default webpage
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(value));
            context.startActivity(i);

        } else if (value.startsWith("@")) { 
            value = value.replace("@", ""); //To get the text without the @

            System.out.println(value);





        } else if (value.startsWith("#")) { 
            value = value.replace("#", ""); //To get the text without the #

            System.out.println(value);


        }
    }

}
```

paste this in a class (can be the same)

```
void setLinks(TextView tv, String text) {
        String[] linkPatterns = {
                "([Hh][tT][tT][pP][sS]?:\\/\\/[^ ,'\">\\]\\)]*[^\\. ,'\">\\]\\)])",
                "#[\\w]+", "@[\\w]+" };
        for (String str : linkPatterns) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(str);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tv.getText());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                int x = matcher.start();
                int y = matcher.end();
                final android.text.SpannableString f = new android.text.SpannableString(
                        tv.getText());
                InternalURLSpan span = new InternalURLSpan(context);
                span.text = text.substring(x, y);
                f.setSpan(span, x, y,
                        android.text.Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                tv.setText(f);
                // tv.setOnLongClickListener(span.l);

            }
        }
        tv.setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        tv.setLinksClickable(true);
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        tv.setFocusable(false);
    }
```

Then use this:

```
setLinks(textView, "THE TEXT WHERE THE LINK IS IN, FOR EX. http://www.google.nl will be underlined and clickable #this_will_also_be_clickable @this_is_clickable_too");
```

Comment: Its like we are getting some strings from the web. And we want these strings to be clickable, and direct us to some pages individually. And the strings we are getting will vary for different users and in number too

Comment: You can use the strings from the web in the code perfectly! Just replace "THE TEXT WHERE...." with your string and it should work just fine